# adblock and jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, adblock

It seems like adblock for Chrome is preventing jquery's $.load() command from being executed. I looked around the web a little and couldn't find anything about this. It doesn't seem to block other jquery, such as $.ajax. I threw a little message on the main page of my site to warn users, but I'd rather find a fix or workaround. Anyone heard of this problem before?

Comment: showing some code might do you some good since I've never encountered any problems between using `$.load` and chrome's adblock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you're retreiving with .load() is injected in a div named publicity, advertising or something similar that get blocked by adblock.

Comment: fwiw this is what the problem turned out to be

Comment: this just saved my life. i had a container named "popup" - even though it was a simple div overlay opened on user event (mouse click), adblock did not open it. renamed it, works fine now. thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery .load() is just shorthand for an Ajax load, so if Ajax is worknig but not .load(), it's probably something you did wrong.